# CarrierWave not uploading files to s3, but to cache (Sinatra app on Heroku)

Tags: ruby, heroku, amazon-s3, sinatra, carrierwave

I have a Sinatra app which takes in an image and am trying to upload that to s3. The response I receive says that the model is successfully saved, but the image URL it returns on saving is the cached upload. No image shows up in the s3 bucket either. The code is below, is there an obvious error? I was following the [Railscast #383](http://railscasts.com/episodes/383-uploading-to-amazon-s3?autoplay=true) episode on uploading to s3.

Any help is appreciated, I've tried a bunch of things to no avail.

app.rb

```
    before do
        #Configure Carrierwave
        CarrierWave.configure do |config|
            config.storage = :fog

            config.fog_credentials = {
                provider: "AWS",
                aws_access_key_id: ENV['s3_access_key_id'],
                aws_secret_access_key: ENV['s3_secret_access_key']
            }

            config.fog_directory = ENV['s3_bucket']
            config.fog_public = true
        end
    end

    post "/nominations" do
        image = params[:file] || nil

        nomination = Nomination.create({
            image: image
        })

        if nomination.valid?
            nomination.save

            status 201
            body nomination.image.url
        else
            status 500
            body nomination.errors.messages.to_s.to_json
        end
    end
end
```

image_uploader.rb

```
require "carrierwave"
require 'carrierwave/storage/fog'

class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :fog

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

nomination.rb

```
class Nomination < ActiveRecord::Base
    extend CarrierWave::Mount

    attr_accessor :image

    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

Comment: You'll probably get more views if you add the `ruby` tag to this, probably in place of `amazon-web-services` as that's kind of covered by the `amazon-s3` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded it directly through s3:

```
image = params[:file] || ''

uri = URI::Data.new(image)

filename = nom.id.to_s + "_" + Time.now.strftime('%Y%b%d_%H:%M:%S') + '.png'
s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(
  access_key_id: ENV.fetch('s3_access_key_id'),
  secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('s3_secret_access_key'),
  region: ENV.fetch('s3_region'),
)
response = s3.put_object(bucket: ENV.fetch('s3_bucket'), key: filename, body: uri.data, acl: "public-read")

image = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/" + ENV.fetch('s3_bucket') + "/" + filename
```